# Solving $P+P=Q$ on the curve $y^2=x^3-n^2x$

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-progressions

If $P=(x_0,y_0)$ is a rational point on the curve $y^2=x^3-n^2x$, let  $Q=2P=P+P=(x_1,y_1)$. Then $x_1$, $x_1+n$ and $x_1-n$ are all rational squares (see for example Ch 1 of the book Elliptic curves and cryptography by L. Washington). I would like to know what can be said instead by going in the reverse direction, that is, suppose we have a rational point $Q=(x_1,y_1)$ on the curve, and we solve the equations corresponding to the group law addition to get a point $P=(x_0,y_0)$ such that $P+P=Q$. I did this and found 
$x_0=x_1\pm \sqrt{x_1^2-n^2}\pm \sqrt{2x_1^2\pm 2x_1 \sqrt{x_1^2-n^2}}$, where using $+++,+-+,-+-,---$ for the three $\pm$ signs actually gives four solutions. Clearly $x_0$ doesn't have to be rational, but what extension of $\mathbb Q$ do we need? For a specific example when $n=5$, consider the point $(x_1,y_1)=(-4,6)$ on the curve $y^2=x^3-25x$. Notice that $-4=(2i)^2$, $-4+5=1^2$ and $-4-5=(3i)^2$, and using the $+++$ sign pattern in the above formula we get $(x_0,y_0)=(2+i,1-7i)$. So $x_0$ is in the extension of $\mathbb Q$ obtained by simply adjoining $\sqrt{x_1}=\sqrt{-4}$. Is this always the case? I guess my question could also be phrased: what extension of a field $k$ do we need to halve points of an elliptic curve defined over $k$? I imagine this is all well-known and written somewhere, but I am new to elliptic curves. I searched the archives but I did not find an answer. I may not know the right search words to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this curve is related to the [congruent number problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number). More precisely, in Proposition 9.19 in Introduction to Elliptic curves and Modular Forms by N. Koblitz, it is stated that there is a 1-1 correspondence between pair of points $(x,\pm y) \in 2E_{n}(\mathbb{Q})-O$ and right-angled triangles with rational sides $X,Y,Z$ and area $n$. One side of this correspondence is given by
\begin{equation}
(x, \pm y) \mapsto (X,Y,Z)=(\sqrt{x+n} - \sqrt{x-n},\sqrt{x+n}+\sqrt{x-n},2\sqrt{x} ).
\end{equation}

So, a point $P=(x,y)$ can be "halved over $\mathbb{Q}$ if $\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x-n},\sqrt{x+n} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, but I do not have enough reputation to comment.

Note that if $m$ is the order of $Q$ and $m$ is not even, $P = [d]Q$, where $d = 2^{-1} \pmod m$.

Thus you can only limit yourself to studying the points $Q$ of even order.